# Typescript: how to get a list of values acceptable/defined by interface?

Tags: typescript

How to get a list of values acceptable/defined by interface?

Example I have a local state defined as:

```
interface LocalState {
    justifyContent: 'space-between' | 'center' | 'flex-start' | 'flex-end' | 'space-around' | 'space-evenly';
}
```

And I want to get an array of items which will contain

```
['space-between', 'center', 'flex-start', 'flex-end', 'space-around', 'space-evenly']
```

Is it possible to extract this information from TS type-system?(Or does it get stripped out while transpiling to Javascript)

If it is possible how?

Comment: Interface has NO footprint in the generated JavaScript, so it doesn't fit for the intended purpose. Use a class instead.
More on interfaces in the docs - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 2):

```
const contentPositions = <const>["space-between", "center", "flex-start", "flex-end", "space-around", "space-evenly"];

interface LocalState {
  justifyContent: typeof contentPositions[number];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since types/interfaces are a concept related to types, and JS is an extremely dynamically typed language... it wouldn't be a great idea.
That being said, we can create an `enum` with all the required properties and simply use JS `Object.values()` to get an array from it. Of course, we can use the enum as a type.

```
enum LocalState {
    spaceBetween = 'space-between',
    center = 'center',
    flexStart = 'flex-start'
}

const localStateArr: LocalState[] = Object.values(LocalState);

console.log(localStateArr) // logs ["space-between", "center", "flex-start"]
```

Partial Example: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMg9gYwIYBsDKAXJHhQN4BQUxUAzgA5ILABCwGA7sKFALxQDkFVwAtAEb0moDgBoiJaiBwAnNpymyxE4gDMUwAB6YkMjPI7qtvUlj0cCAXwIEEcEKagpEqHTgCCMmQC5YL9Fg4ANoAuvIA8vwAVsAIGAB0AG6oYMCkABTwyAHYwACUANw2dg5wGvHOAObpztluwJ4yeVAA9C1OcJWkUEEARNzUAkLMIL2iUL2KwDJjE0aaJmYYvSEEQA)

This is how you can create a simple interface and use it.

```
interface LocalStateWithEnum {
    string : LocalState;
}

// or even more strict:

interface LocalStateWithEnumStrict {
    'justifyContent' :  LocalState;
}

const a: LocalStateWithEnumStrict = {
   justifyContent : LocalState.center
}
```

Full example: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMg9gYwIYBsDKAXJHhQN4BQUxUAzgA5ILABCwGA7sKFALxQDkFVwAtAEb0moDgBoiJaiBwAnNpymyxE4gDMUwAB6YkMjPI7qtvUlj0cCAXwIEEcEKagpEqHTgCCMmQC5YL9Fg4ANoAuvIA8vwAVsAIGAB0AG6oYMCkABTwyAHYwACUANw2dg5wGvHOAObpztluwJ4yeVAA9C1OcJWkUEEARNzUAkLMIL2iUL2KwDJjE0aaJmYYvSE2AJbS06o8fnWBwADqaxgAFgCi4NCEJGQYMhuVUL5ZrvtF1gRtUHBywIksEB+uFM9zi3nWmxk22ou1euSOpwukEwoP01xIHCiYFMa1UAE8AML2HDSDhPYgvHI4d7FeyOJDPfz1BHnS4otZxeToqBYnH4ombaTkyn1eJTGRWIA)

Comment: Using a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) (`'space-between' | 'center' | ...`) rather than enums would be a more straightforward approach. It's too easy to mistakenly use values vs keys in enums. Here's an interesting reading - [Wonderland of TypeScript enums](https://alex-klaus.com/typescript-enum/)